# Format the body text of a gmail using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to figure out 'how-to' format the body of a Gmail that is created and sent via Google Apps Script. I've added `<bold>` to the message, but it does not bold the text, it only displays the characters `<bold>`.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

Thanks

```
var emailAddress = row[34];  // adminEmail column
var message = "<html><body>The " + row[9] + " event that was submitted by <bold>" + row[1] + "</bold> has not been approved yet. Please go to " + row[27] + " and review the admin notes.</body></html>";       
var subject = "An alert for " + row[1] + " needs approval"; 
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Comment: I added `<html>` and `<body>`, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var emailAddress = row[34];  // adminEmail column
var message = "The " + row[9] + " event that was submitted by <b>" + row[1] + "</b> has not been approved yet. Please go to " + row[27] + " and review the admin notes.";       
var subject = "An alert for " + row[1] + " needs approval"; 
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', {
  htmlBody: message
});
```

use `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`
you can use the option `htmlBody` to enter `HTML`

see documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)).

also `<bold>`doesn't work and is not a valid `HTML`tag so use `<b></b>` instead

Comment: Thank you JSmith!